# generating reports in Jenkins

Tags: junit, jenkins

Need to run a job in Jenkins after successfully running the tests it needs to perform as post-build action for generating test reports

For this i have configured

Publish JUnit test result report

In the field

**Test Report XMLs**: continuum/*/target/surefire-reports/*TestSuite.xml

'**continuum/*/target/surefire-reports/*TestSuite.xml' doesn't match anything: 'continuum' exists but not 'continuum/*/target/surefire-reports/*TestSuite.xml'**

Can you please  help me out in resolving the error....??

Comment: it can find the folder continuum but not the file TestSuite.xml. Have you checked ure spelling?

Comment: Yes, the problem is there are many folders in continnum and i need to give the path so that it searches every folder and sees if target is present or not if not , it moves to the next folder..

Comment: Just for clarification.
TestSuite.xml can be in different folders?

Comment: Yes..Even i have tried with single folder continuum/project/target/surefire-reports/*TestSuite.xml I got the following error   continuum/project/target/surefire-reports/TestSuite.xml' doesn't match anything: 'continuum' exists but not 'continuum/project/target/surefire-reports/*TestSuite.xml'

Comment: try this one please continuum/project/target/surefire-reports/*.xml

Comment: Tried with single folder 'continuum/project/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'  geeting the same error...

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have an 'Execute JUnit tests' Build step.  This will produce a JUnit XML file to a location you specify, say, TestOutput/junitresults.xml.

In the 'Publish JUnit test result report' Post Build step you just need to specify TestOutput/junitresults.xml.

As long as your tests executed and produced the output file the Post Build step won't fail to publish it, whether the tests failed or not.

You shouldn't be trying to publish files in the surefire-reports directory unless that it where you told JUnit to write its output file.  Normally you wouldn't.

If you want to make it even simpler just tell JUnit to write its output file to the Jenkins WORKSPACE root by removing the TestOutput/ and just specify junitresults.xml.